# How to get all WordPress pages associated with BuddyPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

How to get all WordPress pages associated with BuddyPress? What I mean, I will elaborate it by an image below:

[image]

As everyone can see according to image there are 5 pages (Widgets, Testing Purpose, Home, About Us, Blog), these are the WordPress pages that are created by me and all these pages are assigned to BuddyPress component directory. Now I want to get all these assigned pages. Is there a builtin function for this purpose or is there any strategy to get these pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the function `bp_core_get_directory_page_ids` which is defined in the file `bp-core/bp-core-functions.php`.

```
/**
 * Fetch a list of BP directory pages from the appropriate meta table.
 *
 * @since BuddyPress (1.5.0)
 *
 * @param string $status 'active' to return only pages associated with active components, 'all' to return all saved
 *                       pages. When running save routines, use 'all' to avoid removing data related to inactive
 *                       components. Default: 'active'.
 * @return array|string An array of page IDs, keyed by component names, or an
 *                      empty string if the list is not found.
 */
function bp_core_get_directory_page_ids( $status = 'active' ) {
```

It will return an array similar to:

```
array(4) {
  ["activity"]=>
  int(72)
  ["members"]=>
  int(73)
  ["register"]=>
  int(74)
  ["activate"]=>
  int(75)
}
```

The array values are the page ID's in WordPress which are assigned to those components.